# Send REST API to Parse from Android

Tags: android, rest, parse-platform

I want to send REST API to the Parse server from Android.
Is any library or class recommended for this ?

I need to send a complex API like in the Parse Docs example:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "user": {
            "$inQuery": {
              "location": {
                "$nearSphere": {
                  "__type": "GeoPoint",
                  "latitude": 30.0,
                  "longitude": -20.0
                },
                "$maxDistanceInMiles": 1.0
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Free hotdogs at the Parse concession stand!"
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

The libraries i've seen send REST API in the format that has the header and then pairs of strings.
How can i send the complex script like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making request to a REST API I usually use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) by Square.

You can make a POST with the JSON object you need. Take a look at the [recipes page](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) at `Posting a String` section. Change the Mediatype for `application/json`, build your JSONObject and pass it to the `Request`

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.parse.com/1/push")
        .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON, json.toString()))
        .build();
```

In order to build the `JSONObject` you can base your code in this snippet:

```
    JSONObject outer = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
    inner.put("key", "value");
    outer.put("otherJSON", inner);
    System.out.println(outer);
```

The result of that `println` is `{"otherJSON":{"key":"value"}}` so you can put as many objects as you want into a `JSONObject`

Comment: So if i understand correctly, i can put all the data of the object as a string, including parentheses and colons ?

Comment: Yes, but I think it would be easier to build a JSONObject with all the info and add it to the body request

Comment: Can you please post an example of building JSONObject with similar complexity ?

Comment: That's quite a simple task. I've edited my answer to provide a little example. In your case the code will have more lines but will be basically the same